# implementation of BST algorithm

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I want to transform this algorithm in python. The algorithm have to build the tree based in BST algorithm. When I run my code they give me 0 as result.

I am doing it recursively:

```
def complet(self,li=[]):
       N=len(li)
       n=log2(N+1)
       delta=N-2**(n-1)
       delta=delta+1
       m1=2**(n-1)
       m1=m1-1
       m2=(2**(n-2))/2
       if delta <= m2: x=m1+delta
       else: x=m1
       self=Noeud(x)
       if len(li)==1: return self
       else:
        lg=li[int(len(li)/2):]
        ld=li[:int(len(li)/2)]
        self.gauche=self.complet(lg)
        self.droit=self.complet(ld)
       return self
```

[bst algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ5lI.jpg)

my code :

```
from math import log2
import cmath
import math
L=["0111","10000","11100","100011","11","1","010" ]
def sort(l=[]):
 for n in range(0,len(l)):
  while len(l[n])<8:
    l[n]=l[n]+"1"
 print(l)
 for k in range(0,len(l)):
     for j in range(k,len(l)):
       if int(l[j],2)> int(l[k],2):
           bj=l[j]
           l[j]=l[k]
           l[k]=bj
 print(l)
 return l
sort(L)
class Noeud:
    def __init__(self,va):
        self.droit=None
        self.gauche=None
        self.valur=va
    def complet(self,li=[]):
       N=len(li)
       n=log2(N+1)
       delta=N-2**(n-1)
       delta=delta+1
       m1=2**(n-1)
       m1=m1-1
       m2=(2**(n-2))/2
       if delta <= m2: x=m1+delta
       else: x=m1
       self=Noeud(x)
       if len(li)==1: return self
       else:
        lg=li[int(len(li)/2):]
        ld=li[:int(len(li)/2)]
        self.gauche=self.complet(lg)
        self.droit=self.complet(ld)
       return self
    def printTree(self):

          if self.gauche:
            self.printTree(self.gauche)
          print(self.valur, end="")
          if self.droit:
            self.printTree(self.droit)

ar=Noeud(0)
ar.complet(L)
ar.printTree()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `printTree` method is parameterless, however, you are passing it `self.gauche` and `self.droit`. Instead you should be calling the printTree() method on the left (`gauche`) and right (`droit`) nodes:

```
def printTree(self):
    if self.gauche:
        self.gauche.printTree()
    print(self.valur, end="")
    if self.droit:
        self.droit.printTree()
```

Secondly you are not using the value returned by your `complet` method. You can fix this as follows:

```
ar=Noeud(0)
ar2 = ar.complet(L)
ar2.printTree()
```